# Custom line break and column sizing in table

Tags: tables, xetex, columns, multicolumn

I use the following code to produce a table (using XeLaTex):

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}

%---- Allow the insertion of graphics and tables ----%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

%---- Set margins ----%
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{a4paper,total={210mm,297mm},
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=25mm,
 bottom=25mm,
 }

%---- Set line spacing to 1.5 lines ----%
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

%----- Set fonts ----%

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Table title}
\resizebox{160mm}{!}{    
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}[2]{*}{\textbf{Col. 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Section 1 title}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Extremely long section title in multicolumn}} \\
          & \textbf{Subtitle A} & \textbf{Subtitle B} & \textbf{Subtitle C} & \textbf{Subtitle C} \\
   \midrule
    Row 1  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
    Row 2  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
    Row 3  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
    Row 4  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
    Row 5  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
        \toprule
    \textbf{Total} & \textbf{xxx} & \textbf{xxx} & \textbf{xxx} & \textbf{xxx} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
}
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

I would like to do two things:

- Manually insert line breaks in certain cells:

  "Subtitle A" and "Subtitle B" - insert breaks between "Subtitle" and "A"/"B"

  "Extremely long..." - insert break between "Extremely long section" and "title in multicolumn"
- Make the columns "Subtitle A" to "Subtitle D" the same width (larger than "Col. 1")

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve all this with David Carlisle's `tabularx` package. I thought to provide 2 different solutions, since manual breaks can be done inside a `tabular` environment, but that does not solve your problem properly IMO.

Column width is fixed within `tabularx` preamble:

`>{\centering\arraybackslash}X` means "centered-text (`>{\centering\arraybackslash}`), fixed-width (`X`) column". This fixed width depends on `tabularx` total width.
In place of `\centering` you could use `\raggedleft` or `\raggedright`. Default `X` column has text aligned to the left.

This is the first solution, which uses manual breaks, using command `\break`. Notice that manual `\break` is not working in `\multicolumn`'s argument, therefore the *extremely long title* cannot be splitted.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{a4paper,
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=25mm,
 bottom=25mm,
 }

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Table title}
    \begin{tabularx}{160mm}
    {c
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}X  %centered-text, fixed-width column
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \toprule
    \multirow{3}[3]{*}{\textbf{Col. 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Section 1 title}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Extremely long section title in multicolumn}} \\
          & \textbf{Subtitle\break A} & \textbf{Subtitle\break B} & \textbf{\break Subtitle C} & \textbf{\break Subtitle D} \\
   \midrule
    Row 1  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
    Row 2  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
    Row 3  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
    Row 4  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
    Row 5  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
        \toprule
    \textbf{Total} & \textbf{xxx} & \textbf{xxx} & \textbf{xxx} & \textbf{xxx} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

The second one doesn't use `\break`, it has one more row to properly arrange every subtitle.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{a4paper,
 left=20mm,
 right=20mm,
 top=25mm,
 bottom=25mm,
 }

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Table title}
    \begin{tabularx}{160mm}
    {c
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}X  %centered-text, fixed-width column
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \toprule
    \multirow{3}[3]{*}{\textbf{Col. 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Section 1 title}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Extremely long section}} \\
    &\textbf{Subtitle}&\textbf{Subtitle}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{title in multicolumn}}\\
          &\textbf{A} &\textbf{B} & \textbf{Subtitle C} & \textbf{Subtitle D} \\
   \midrule
    Row 1  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
    Row 2  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
    Row 3  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
    Row 4  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
    Row 5  &  xxx &  xxx &  xxx & xxx \\
        \toprule
    \textbf{Total} & \textbf{xxx} & \textbf{xxx} & \textbf{xxx} & \textbf{xxx} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: With `\\ `is impossible: `LaTeX` will think there is a tabular end of line. You can use `\break` as in the first solution, but it creates a new line and moves down all the following rows without an explicit specification in the code. And this makes me feel unconfortable.

Comment: Cool answer! What about `\par` instead of `\break`? This was my "manually"-habit...which one is better?

Answer (score 2):

The `makecell` package is done for that: it allows for linebreaks in cells, and common formatting for column heads. Also you shouldn't use `\esizebox` as it also scales the text in a tabular. I used the `tabulars` environment instead, with a table total width of 16 cm.. Although one should not use `\multicolumn`s that come across `X` type columns, it seems to be working in the present case. Finally, I loadd the `caption`  package to ensure proper vertical spacing between caption and table.

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper]{article}

%---- Allow the insertion of graphics and tables ----%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

%---- Set margins ----%
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, hmargin=20mm, vmargin=25mm }

%---- Set line spacing to 1.5 lines ----%
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

%----- Set fonts ----%

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\usepackage{caption}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Table title}
\label{tab:addlabel}%
\begin{tabularx}{160mm}{c*{4}{X}}
\toprule
&  multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Section 1 title}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Extremely long section\\ title in multicolumn}} \\
\thead{Col. 1} & \thead{Subtitle\\ A} & \thead{Subtitle\\ B} & \thead{Subtitle\\ C} & \thead{Subtitle\\ D} \\
\midrule\addlinespace
Row 1 & xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
Row 2 & xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
Row 3 & xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
Row 4 & xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
Row 5 & xxx & xxx & xxx & xxx \\
\addlinespace
    \toprule
\textbf{Total} & \textbf{xxx} & \textbf{xxx} & \textbf{xxx} & \textbf{xxx} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]